# Await API calls before render private route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have protected routes that passing auth enabled true or false to allow users access auth page. Every page load, it calls the auth token API and check for valid. If token invalid, redirect to login page.

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({isEnabled, ...props}) => {
    return (isEnabled) ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login"/>;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**Routes.js**

```
import {withRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default withRouter(({ location }) => {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false)
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      if(accessToken){
        let res = await ValidateLoginToken(accessToken)
        if (res && res.data && res.data.status === 200){
          setIsAuth(res.data.valid)
        } else setIsAuth(false);
      } else setIsAuth(false)
    })()
   },[isAuth])

  return (
    <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} isEnabled={isAuth} />
        <Route path="/" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

**App.js**

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Routes/>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
export const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
   <div class="ui form-user center raised padded segment">
      <a href="/section1">
        <div id="section1" class="ui floated right basic red button">
           Directory #1
        </div>
      </a>
   </div>
  )
}
```

**Problem**

> When auth users browse authenticated page (Dashboard), redirects to login page. The reason is that verify token API returns after ProtectedRoute rendered as isAuth equals to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the initial state as `null` to differentiate the different states of your component.

- null -> API token no called yet.
- true -> token verified
- false -> token verification failed.

```
export default function ProtectedRoute(props) {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = React.useState(false)
  const history = useHistory();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function validateToken() {
      if(accessToken){
        let res = await ValidateLoginToken(accessToken)
        if (res && res.data && res.data.status === 200){
          setIsAuth(true)
          return;
        }
      } 

      history.push('/login')
    } 
    
    validateToken();
   }, [isAuth]);

   if (isAuth === null) return null;

   return props.children;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <ProtectedRoute> 
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </ProtectedRoute>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: It won't redirect to login for non-authorized user because return false. If I placed login route in `isAuth === null`, users will direct Login UI page, then redirect to dashboard, which is not what I wanted. `Should be redirect to dashboard without showing login`

Comment: What's your Dashboard component look like?

Comment: I've updated the code above. Do check again. It should be working.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `isAuth` being a boolean, you use a string or number to increase the number of states. For example rename `isAuth` to `loginState` which can be `"pending"`, `"authenticated"` or `"unauthenticated"`. Then use `"pending"` as the initial state and add an additional scenario. You could for example return `null` to render nothing, render a spinning circle, etc.

Here is an example rendering `null` (nothing) while the login token is being authenticated:

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
const loginRoutes = {
  pending:         (        ) => null,
  authenticated:   (...props) => <Route {...props} />,
  unauthenticated: (        ) => <Redirect to="/login"/>,
};

const ProtectedRoute = ({loginState = "pending", ...props}) => {
  const LoginRoute = loginRoutes[loginState];
  return <LoginRoute {...props} />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**Route.js**

```
import { withRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default withRouter(({ location }) => {
  const [loginState, setLoginState] = useState("pending")
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      if(accessToken){
        let res = await ValidateLoginToken(accessToken)
        if (res && res.data && res.data.status === 200) {
          setLoginState(res.data.valid ? "authenticate" : "unauthenticated")
        } else setLoginState("unauthenticated");
      } else setLoginState("unauthenticated")
    })()
   }, [loginState])

  return (
    <Switch>
      <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} loginState={loginState} />
      <Route path="/" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

As a disclaimer, I have no experience with React Router so I've kept the example as close to the original as possible.

Comment: React return error when ProtectedRoute return null. `return (LoginRoute) ? <LoginRoute {...props} /> : <></>;` will run.

Comment: @Abel What is the error? I suspect you you call `ProtectedRoute` without `loginState` somewhere in your code. In that case use a default prop for the component. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another state variable to wait for api execution before initializing routes.

```js
const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false)
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      if(accessToken){
        let res = await ValidateLoginToken(accessToken)
        if (res && res.data && res.data.status === 200){
          setIsAuth(res.data.valid)
        } else setIsAuth(false);
      } else setIsAuth(false)
    setChecked(true)
})()
   },[isAuth])
```

Then in Routes, you can do something like:

```js
 <Switch>
        {
        !checked?(<React.Fragment/>):!isAuth?(<Route path="/" component={Login} />):(<ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} loginState={loginState} />)
        }
 </Switch>
```

I usually separate session routes and no session routes in separate hooks and it works fine.